# Dynamically create a compiled .NET exe from source code?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

I need to inject a custom, unique, static string into my .NET based EXE.  For all intents and purposes, assume that this is my Private key of a PKI.

I have a few ideas on how I'll approach protecting the Private key within the C# source code, my question is how do I take my .CS files and create an executable based off it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx), which can essentially be used take a string containing source code and compile it to an assembly (EXE or DLL), or if you require, an in memory assembly.

You can also use the [codeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) for the code generation side of things. Take a look at ['Generating Source Code and Compiling a Program from a CodeDOM Graph'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06.aspx) as a starting point.

Comment: An "in memory" assembly.  Fascinating.  When would I use one?  Sounds like that may be a good fit

Comment: @MakerOfThings7, in memory assemblies are nice when you want to support things like dynamically generating code based on user input and have that execute on demand without having the binary saved to disk, supporting things like macros etc. Of course .NET has evolved this you can also use things like Dynamic Methods etc. Here is a link for the dynamic method stuff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be to call [csc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx), the C# compiler.

For example: (from the msdn page linked above)

```
csc /out:My.exe File.cs
```

Would produce an executable called `My.exe` from an input file called `File.cs`.

If the executable you want to compile is fairly complex, it might prove simpler to keep that pre-compiled and only compile a DLL that it calls a method in at runtime to obtain the private key, as that would be a simpler command line to pass to csc.

Comment: Is csc always installed with .NET? What about the client framework (lighter version of .NET)?

Comment: @MakerOfThings, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx, msbuild is *not* included, but it doesn't say either way regarding csc/vbc. I'd assume they are as they're core components, but I don't have a framework-less PC to verify that on I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, scs.exe and vbc.exe _are_ included in the runtime, not the SDK. So they are on every target machine.